# Problems passing parameters to a dynamic method (object_addMethod)

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime

I'm attempting to use `resolveClassMethod:` and `object_addMethod` to add a new method. Things seem to be working fine in general, but the parameter doesn't seem to be coming through.

When I pass in a parameter, such as:

```
UIFont *font1 = [UIFont academyEngravedLetPlainOfSize:12.0f];
```

I get 0.0 instead of 12.0 for the font size in my dynamic method. Here's the output from the sample below:

```
createNamedFontIMP(UIFont, academyEngravedLetPlainOfSize:, 0.000000)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

```
@interface UIFont (NTNamedFonts)

+(UIFont *)academyEngravedLetPlainOfSize:(int)size NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0);

@end

@implementation UIFont (NTNamedFonts)

NSString *targetSelectorName = @"academyEngravedLetPlainOfSize:";
NSString *targetFontName = @"AcademyEngravedLetPlain";

+(BOOL)resolveClassMethod:(SEL)sel
{
    NSString *selectorName = NSStringFromSelector(sel);

    if ( [selectorName isEqualToString:targetSelectorName] )
    {
        Class metaClass = object_getClass(self);
        class_addMethod(metaClass, sel, (IMP)createNamedFontIMP, "@#:f");
        return YES;
    }
    else
        return [super resolveClassMethod:sel];
}

static id createNamedFontIMP(Class class, SEL _cmd, CGFloat size)
{
    NSLog(@"createNamedFontIMP(%@, %@, %f)", NSStringFromClass(class), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), size);

    UIFont *font = [class fontWithName:targetFontName size:size];

    return font;
}

@end
```

Comment: Turns out this was a typo on my part, the declaration should be (CGFloat)size instead of (int)size. Oops!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass an integer to a float. Please show the method declaration.

BTW: What's the reason for your code? A category seems to be the better approach.

BTW 2: If I remember correctly, you have to use double.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm trying to do. I've added the declaration for additional context.

Comment: I still do not understand, what your final goal is. However the method declaration takes an integer as parameter, the signature expects a float. Fix that.

Comment: Aww crap. Yeah one of those times I needed someone looking over my shoulder to see my stupid mistake ;) The declaration is created by a code generator and it looks like I fat fingered it. Works great now, Thanks!!!

Comment: Shit happens … For this kind of errors the web is perfect. One will never find the mistake himself.